# jquery ui dialog box not opening in html on click of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to open a dialog box in html page on click of a link but its showing me an error like-Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' on click in ie.

Please check my code below

source files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Dialog code

```
$("#link").click(function(c){

                e.preventDefault();
          var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({

            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {alert('you chose yes');},
                "No":  function() {alert('you chose no');},
                "Cancel":  function() {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
            }); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a div set up that will be the dialog, like in this example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
 
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information.     The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's a jsbin with a working example with buttons](http://jsbin.com/xolici/1/)

Comment: But i need to run this dialog on click of a link which is nt happening sir.

Comment: Its working the wa you gave but when click function is added it stops working

Comment: Is this error related to script sources which i m linking

Comment: I don't know.  Does the exact code I pasted above work for you?  That would be the first thing to test.  If the exact code works, then replace with your script sources, and test again.

Comment: still the same sir with updated code....may b the problem is with script sources.isnt it

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "c" with an "e" and remove the closing brackets at the end. You had one too many.

```
$("#link").click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
      var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({

        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {alert('you chose yes');},
            "No":  function() {alert('you chose no');},
            "Cancel":  function() {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
        });
```

Comment: I used ur fiddle code as well.but still i m getting the same error on IE

Comment: try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/2xaz90y7/6/embedded/result/

I don't think your scripts are being loaded, try https

Comment: hmm.its loading in plain html but when i m putting in my jsp its throwing the error